# RestKit RKDynamicObjectMapping work only for first JSON result

Tags: ios, rest, wcf-data-services, restkit

i got into an issue with `RKDynamicObjectMapping`, however it could be 
that i misuse it.

I have the following scenario

1. request to the service to get areas
2. choose area
3. request to the service to get journals for selected area

data returned by both calls looks like that

```
{ d: [{cutID:""}, {cutID:""}, {cutID:""}] } 
{ d: [{journalID:""}, {journalID:""}, {journalID:""}] }
```

i have the following code

```
RKObjectMapping* cutMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Cut 
class]]; 
[cutMapping mapKeyPath:@"CutID" toAttribute:@"cutID"]; 
RKObjectMapping* journalMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: 
[Journal class]]; 
[journalMapping mapKeyPath:@"journalID" toAttribute:@"journalID"]; 
RKDynamicObjectMapping * dynamicMapping  = [RKDynamicObjectMapping 
dynamicMapping]; 
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:journalMapping 
whenValueOfKeyPath:@"__metadata.type" isEqualTo:@"JournalDetails"]; 
[dynamicMapping setObjectMapping:cutMapping 
whenValueOfKeyPath:@"__metadata.type" isEqualTo:@"Cut"]; 
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] 
setMapping:dynamicMapping forKeyPath:@"d"]; 

.... 

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:getResourcePath 
delegate:self]; 

....
```

and later

```
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:getResourcePath 
delegate:obj];
```

results of first request, which returns `Cut` objects, is mapped flawlessly, but not for second which returns `Journal` objects. 
logging in `request:didLoadResponse` showed that service returns 
expected json , so the issue is with mappings 
how to make it work with two mappings ?

Anyone using RestKit Dynamic Mapping yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you've checked that your **Cut** object is mapping to a *to-many* relationship in the CoreData entity?

If so can you turn on the RESTKit logging and post the results

Comment: nope i haven't, actually i don't use CoreData at all yet.
can you also point me on how to turn on logging which results you want to see ?

Comment: Sorry, my presumption on the CoreData ;o) - It's very cool, well worth spending the time learning about.

Unfortunately the Logging is not documented in the API docs, but if you browse through the RESTKit examples you'll see ref to the `RKLog<xxx>` types & methods being used, for example.
`RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelInfo);`
`RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelTrace);`

Comment: doesn't seem that any one else is going to help so i'll just give you the award

Comment: Thanks ;o).. Have you resolved your issue though? If not did the logs give any further clues?