# Segue configured but not fired

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, storyboard, segue

I have the following setup of my storyboard

NC --> TVC  --> VC --> TVC --> VC

Problem I face is that first segue from TableViewController to ViewController does work
and the second does not. 
Both are configured as push segues ( actual all transitions are configured this way ) 
Both tables are filled in dynamically.
Just First one works and second not.
What could be an issue ? 
segues has named set up , table cells has ids, 
event on selecting table cell is firing in both cases, however prepare for segue is not firing in second case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably going to need to see some code.  Without seeing it, make sure:

- Make sure you have the Segue wired up to the View
- You have specified and are using the right Segue identifier
- Make sure you are calling [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil]; in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: first two checked but for third i do not do this even in that case that works

Comment: actually adding performSegueWithIdentifier fixed my problem, so the remaining question is, why it works in first case without this extra line of code.

Comment: Depends on how you have the Segue wired up.  It can be (and probably is) tied to your TableView rather than the View itself in the other VC that is working.  My suggestion is to almost always wire it up to the View and take care of Segue action on your own.  One exception is if you are using a Static Cell TableViewController.  Then you can just wire up the Segue to the cell.

Comment: I just dragged TVC and VC from right panel and right click drug segue from table cell to VC.

Comment: btw, have you ever used RestKit ? take a look at my second question on iOS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942696/restkit-rkdynamicobjectmapping-work-only-for-first-json-result